# real time asynchronous tasks with cocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, task-queue, grand-central-dispatch

I'm making a soap client, and i need to do some time-based and priority operations.. for example.. i need to process every 200msec the call x, every 2 seconds the call y, and aleatory call z, that should have maximum priority... but there is another problem, I can make only n calls per second, queueing the other calls..

I've wrote all the soap consuming process, the user interface, but I'm having problems with the dispatcher.. I've tried dispatch queues but I cant find support for this real time and limited processing.. maybe i should write a multi-threaded environment for this?

Comment: Real time and SOPA? Really? Man, you've got determination. Besides, why don't tell in your question what exactly is your problem? Is it performance? Is it the processing? Is it the queuing? When you say *limited processing*, does it mean that your processing stalls the queue? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

iOS/OSX are not [Real Time Operating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)'s. However, have a look at NSOperationQueue which should allow you to achieve mostly  what you're looking for, without manually creating threads yourself:

- [NSOperationQueue Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Cocoa Tutorial: NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue)

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch source timer. In any case, there are no realtime guarantee.

```
dispatch_source_t timerX = dispatch_source_create(
    DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_source_t timerY = dispatch_source_create(
    DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

dispatch_source_set_timer(timerX,
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
        DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 0);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timerY,
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
        DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 0);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerX, ^{
    /* call X */
});
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerY, ^{
    /* call Y */
});

dispatch_resume(timerX);
dispatch_resume(timerY);
```